# RegEx allow any characters for a maximum of 255 for an input tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Using java-script regular expression I need to apply some rule for an input text.

Basically I want to allow any characters, included any spaces with total length from 0 (input could be blank) to maximum 255.

At the moment I am using this, but does not allow me any character

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9$%!_ ]{0,255}'
```

I am trying also this code but does not work

```
"[.]{0,255}"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tip : you can use a website like https://regex101.com/ to test your RegExp (don't forget to select JS) !

Comment: Why regex in this case? :) Just limit number of chars (maxlength attribute), or test length by script...

Comment: in my real app, input tag is generate by dijit framework, I have no control on the markup generated. thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex `[.]{0,255}` matches 0 to 255 literal dots, and the first one just matches 0 to 255 characters from the specified set.

You should use anchors and a limiting quantifier with  a dot:

```
^.{0,255}$
```

If you allow newline symbols, use `[\s\S]` since in JavaScript, there is no inline or regular singleline modifiers:

```
^[\s\S]{0,255}$
```

Comment: @GibboK: Great, I just want to make sure all possible cases are covered.